# increment a variable in bash ` i=0; ls>$((++i)); echo i=$i; ` why the result is i=0

Tags: bash, shell

**case 0**

```
i=0; ls > $((++i)); echo i=$i
```

*create a file : 1*

*and output:*

i=0

*comment: why i=0 ?*

**case 1**

```
i=0; ls $((++i)); echo i=$i
```

*output:*

1

i=1

*comment: the result is correct*

**case 2**

```
i=0; echo > $((++i)); echo i=$i
```

*create a file : 1*

*and output:*

i=1

*comment: the result is correct*

**case 3**

```
i=0; echo 1 | grep $((++i)); echo i=$i
```

*output:*

1

i=0

*comment: maybe case 3 <=> case 0 ?*

**case 4**

```
i=0; command ls > $((++i)); echo i=$i
```

*create a file : 1*

*and output:*

i=1

*comment: why diff with case 0 ?*

**case 5**

```
i=0; { ls; } > $((++i)); echo i=$i
```

*create a file : 1*

*and output :*

i=1

*comment: this case from gniourf_gniourf*

**more cases:**

```
i=0; ( echo ) > $((++i)); echo i=$i   #i=0

i=0; { ls > $((++i)); }; echo i=$i   #i=0
```

**I am very confused, why i=0 in case 0 ?**

Whether it is a bug ?

My bash version : GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (i686-redhat-linux-gnu)

You can try in your bash.

Comment: That's not a bug because they are performing in different namespaces.

Comment: @muradin: There are no namespaces in bash.

Comment: @choroba: Different sessions as you correctly mentioned `subshells` have their own variables. These are not visible to each others and that was what i meant. Not namespaces like other languages like C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between `echo` and `ls` is that `ls` is an external command `/usr/bin/ls`, while `echo` is a shell builtin. Try replacing it with `/usr/bin/echo` (if it exists on your system). You'll get the same behaviour - it seems the redirection happens in a subshell that runs the command.

Compare:

```
$ i=0; /usr/bin/echo > $( ((++i)); echo inside $i>&2; echo $i ) ; echo i=$i
inside 1
i=0
```

Comment: Thank you! I added case 4, why case 4 i=1 ?

Comment: My understanding is that the reason of this behavior is subshell, is it right? No subshell when use " command ls > $((++i)) " ?

Comment: @赵小刚: The redirection happens for `command` which is a builtin, so no subshell. `ls` runs in a subshell, but the redirection already happened.

Comment: Do you think the behaviour of case 0 is reasonable ? I think case 3 is reasonable, but I have no idea about case 0.

Comment: There's another funny case: `{ ls; } > $((++i))`. Surprise!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Yeah, `{` is a shell keyword.

Comment: @choroba: **(** is a shell keyword too, why `i=0; (echo) > $((++i)); echo i=$i` return i=0

Comment: @赵小刚: `(` is not a keyword (try `type {` versus `type (`). `(` starts a subshell, `{` does not.